# Unable to connect to Sybase 15.0.3 Server using Isql

Tags: sybase, connectivity, isql, sybase-ase15

I have installed Sybase ASE 15.0.3 on Read Hat Linux. ASE server is up and running. However, i am not able to connect to the server via iSql.

[sybase@ip-********* install]$ isql -SCLGETCLD -Usa -Pnull
Unable to retrieve localized message for ID 4
CT-LIBRARY error:
        ct__string_extended_encryption: user api layer: internal common library error: Client password encryption fails.

I am using the default password null for sa. I have not set any password for Sa during the installation process.

I have tried looking into the interfaces file and it'looks good. Looked out for the libraries sybase/15/OCS-15_0/lib3p/sybcsi and they are good with right permissions in place.

Not really sure if i am missing something. Any inputs  regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried isql without specifying "-Pnull" as a parameter?

Comment: As John said you can't pass null in with -P if there's no password remove the -P altogether.

Comment: Thank you John and Rich. I have tried without -P still no luck. [sybase@ip- ASE-15_0]$ isql -S********** -Usa
Password:
Unable to retrieve localized message for ID 4
CT-LIBRARY error:
        ct__string_extended_encryption: user api layer: internal common library error: Client password encryption fails.

Comment: Try this without the -P key, but with an empty -X key and post the output.

Comment: Yeah, i did try using the -X key.[sybase@ip-******** 15]$ isql -SHOUETCLD -Usa -X
Password:
Unable to retrieve localized message for ID 4
CT-LIBRARY error:
        ct__string_extended_encryption: user api layer: internal common library error: Client password encryption fails.

Comment: Are your isql session shell environment set to the same $SYBASE, $SYBASE_ASE and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH settings as the database instance? There's a bug with the 15.7 client where if LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not correctly set it throws a similar error.

Are you connecting to the database instance on the same host where it is running?

Comment: Thank you guys for your inputs. I am able to resolve the issue by disabling ASELINUX.   vi /etc/sysconfig/selinux,selinux=disabled.